# I'm Trying to access an array inside an obj but while in the same scope of that object

Tags: javascript, jsdom

```
let imageObj = {
  imgArr: [
    'dead_battery.jpg', 'evolution.jpg', 'funny_cat_pic.jpg',
    'funny_paper_guys.jpg', 'happy_image', 'wood_garden.jpg'
  ],
  currentImg: 0,
  changeImage: (image) => {
    imageCycle = setInterval((image) => {
        let counter = 0;
        let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        image.src = `/images/${imgArr[randomNum]}`;
        console.log('Times Ran: ', counter);
      },
      3000);
  },
  stopImage: (terminate) => {
    if (terminate) clearInterval(imageCycle);
    console.log('INTERVAL STOPPED');
    console.log(imgArr[3]);
  },
  imageCycle: undefined
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access `imgArr`?

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the answer by Angel Politis is correct in what he says, another way to still access the object properties is by **not** using arrow functions to define your functions, but instead use the `function` keyword and then refer to the desired property with the use of `this`.

This will work

```
let obj = {
    arr: ["one", "two"],
    run: function() {
      console.log(this.arr);
    }
}
obj.run();
```

but this won't work

```
let obj = {
    arr: ["one", "two"],
    run: () => {
      console.log(this.arr);
    }
}
obj.run();
```

So by just changing your arrow functions to `function` and refer to the objects using `this`, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Using `imgArr` won't work, because `imgArr` is not a variable, but rather a property of the `imageObj` object. You can use `imageObj.imgArr` to access your array inside the functions.

**Code:**

```js
let imageObj = {
  imgArr: [
    'dead_battery.jpg', 'evolution.jpg', 'funny_cat_pic.jpg',
    'funny_paper_guys.jpg', 'happy_image', 'wood_garden.jpg'
  ],
  currentImg: 0,
  changeImage: (image) => {
    imageObj.imageCycle = setInterval(() => {
      let counter = 0;
      let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
      image.src = '/images/' + imageObj.imgArr[randomNum];
      console.log('Times Ran: ', counter);
    },
    3000);
  },
  stopImage: (terminate) => {
    if (terminate) clearInterval(imageObj.imageCycle);
    console.log('INTERVAL STOPPED');
    console.log(imageObj.imgArr[3]);
  },
  imageCycle: undefined
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!! is that only for arrays or does that apply for everything within the scope of the obj? just wondering

Comment: You're welcome @JoekorSan. I'm glad I could help you. It applies for everything.

Comment: What does the snippet contribute with? You haven't changed anything else but the `image.src = ...` line.

Comment: Nothing @DanielB. When I was creating it, I found the error in that line and I thought I'd correct it to clean up the console. I've removed it now, since it doesn't actually show anything when run.